# twitter oauth webapp with twitter4j is giving me an 403 exception

Tags: oauth, twitter4j

I have a trouble using twitter4j for webapp oauth. The code is:

```
//I changed from val to var 
var twit = TwitterFactory.getSingleton
twit.setOAuthConsumer("oAUMN69x14PKmMhjr3RyQ","1C4fAnW3LAZYG8M4Sl0n9KzYcExW30xTL8S9U")
val reqst = twit.getOAuthRequestToken
```

Right now I'm just testing it, so I generate the url `reqst.getAuthorizationURL`, and copy the **oauth_verifier** from the url

Is not necessary to use **oauth_token**?

http://127.0.0.1/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=2sGINg***n6YSJ4&oauth_verifier=xNdDA*****OfL

```
val tok = twit.getOAuthAccessToken(reqst.getToken, "xNdDA...OfL")
```

This line causes an error

```
twitter4j.TwitterException: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
The screen name / password combination seems to be invalid.
  at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:165)
  at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:372)
  ... 30 elided
Caused by: twitter4j.TwitterException: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><errors><error code="87">Client is not permitted to perform this action</error></errors>

  at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
  at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
  at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
  at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:158)
  ... 31 more
```

What could be the error?